# Insert special characters to a string for web address

Tags: php

Im fetching an array from my sql database, but the string has spaces in it (ie B54DT45 GDT4563 HaK7698).

This needs to go into a webadress like %30B54dT45%20 so that the outcome is

Here is my code:
$pid = mysql_query("SELECT cPushID FROM tblUsers WHERE intUserID='20' AND Length(cPushID) > 70 AND cAlerts = 'All'");
$url = rawurlencode("");
$msg = "test";

file_get_contents("http://domain/push.php?msg=$msg&to=$url");

The string in the database is something like  as an example. That exact string needs to be send to the push.php script on the remote server for it to run correctly

Comment: please indent your code with spaces, so it will be shown as code. Anything between `<>` disappears as well. Enclose inline `<` and `>` in backticks (`\``)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawurlencode()`

because the space must be %20 according to the question.

*edit:* the question wasn't very clear, but to add < and > before encoding, just do

```
rawurlencode("<$txt>");
```

**edit:** the question has evolved into a mysql question, here's a short answer

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `this` FROM `that`");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$this = $row[0];
```

or

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `this` FROM `that`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$this = $row['this'];
```

Comment: didn't seem to work. Here is my code:

$pid = mysql_query("SELECT cPushID FROM tblUsers WHERE intUserID='20' AND Length(cPushID) > 70 AND cAlerts = 'All'");
$url = rawurlencode("<$pid>");
$msg = "test";

file_get_contents("http://domain/push.php?msg=$msg&to=$url");

The string in the database is something like <BC34DH DHSO39 HIRD38> as an example. That exact string needs to be send to the push.php script on the remote server for it to run correctly.

Comment: dude. $pid is a mysql response identifier. If you want the data, do `$row = mysql_fetch_row($pid); $data = $row[0];` and use `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/url_encode) or [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php), depending on if you want spaces as `+` or `%20`.

Comment: I need it to insert a '<' and '>' At th beginning and end

Comment: @BigMike You should add that to the question. And you can simply do `'<' . rawurlencode($string) . '>'`. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode` then `urldecode` it before inserting it to the database.